# Convert from Bitmap to HttpPostedFile

Tags: vb.net

I'm working with asp.net and Visual Basic.

I have a FileUpload field where I receive an image. 
I need to resize than image and the upload it to a ftp server (a external one)

I have a function that receive the HttpPostedFile and convert it to Image with:

```
image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imagen.InputStream)
smallImage = New Drawing.Bitmap(image, New Drawing.Size("widht", "height"))
```

I need to convert "smallImage" to HttpPostedFile OR find out how to upload a BitMap file to my external server but I can't figure it out how to do any of those two options.

Any ideas?

Edit: In order to upload a file to my external server I have:

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(New Uri("myftp"; & fileName))   
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile 
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
```

But I don't know how to continue yet

Comment: Did you consider using [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class?

Comment: I do but i can't make it work.

I have: 
        Dim request As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(New     Uri("ftp://myftp" & fileName))
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "pass")

But I don´t know how continue

Comment: Check this out: [How to: Upload Files with FTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx). Or use UploadFile as suggested below in the answer. The only thing you need is to have this file saved locally first (from what I see on MSDN - it does not support streams).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_methods.aspx) Class. It has several overloaded `UploadFile` methods that can simplify file uploads to FTP.

Comment: I finally did it with that.

I save the image in my server with:  smallImage.Save(Server.MapPath("../directory/" & nameOfImage), ImageFormat.Jpeg). Then, i upload the image from server to server with My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(Server.MapPath("../dir/" & nameOfFile), "ftpAddress" & nameOfFile, "user", "pass")

Answer (score 0):

Don`t know if the conversion is even posible.

I follow the advices up there and:
-Save the image in my principal server

```
smallImage.Save(Server.MapPath("../dir/" & nameOfImage), ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

-Upload the image from my server to my external server

```
 My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(Server.MapPath("../dir/" & nameOfFile), "ftpAddress" & nameOfFile, "user", "pass")
```

-Delete the image from my principal server

It is working just fine.